# IIS Url Resolve

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, iis-7

I have www.mySite.info - working from localhost.

I have www.mySite.info - working from anywhere else.

I have www.mySite.info/Blog - working from localhost

**However www.mySite.info/Blog - not resolving from anywhere else.**

I get  "**No data received Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.**" in Chrome.

IIS Virtual path is /Blog but does not work When I try to access it from the web. Only locally.

Comment: it's browser specific I guess. My problem is that when I browse it from IIS for example of just type in http://www.mySite.info/Blog it resolves to what I have inside the web.config. 

<forms loginUrl="~/Account.aspx/LogOn" timeout="2880" name="BlogConsole"/>


Trying the same thing from the web does not work as expected.

Comment: tried it with/without the `www` ?

Comment: Tried pinging it with a command window? See where it resolves to? Open command window and type `ping www.yourdomain.com/blog`